# Robots.txt - no follow, no index

Tags: robots.txt

Please can someone explain to me the difference between setting allow and disallow in a robots.txt file and create No follow, No index meta tags!
Is it possible to set no follow and no index within the robots.txt file?
I have look on http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html and not really got what im looking for!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The robots.txt file will simple tell a robot where he is allowed to go and where he isn't. It has no power to make a robot follow a link to another website. The nofollow, noindex meta tag will prevent a compliant robot from indexing or following the link specified or the links contained in the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Disallowing a robot in `robots.txt` from a specific page has the same effect setting a `META` tag of `noindex` for that page does.

A `META` tag of `nofollow` prevents search engines from following the links on the page even if they're allowed to index the page itself. There's no `robots.txt` version of this.

`noindex` can be useful in some situations on dynamic sites where a `robots.txt` is not flexible enough. For example, if you had a system that made URLs like `node/123`, blocking articles based on certain data in the article would have to be done with `noindex`, as `robots.txt` can only filter based on stuff in the URL itself.